# Multiple epsilons in Epsilon N proof ,how to proceed?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

While doing tasks I came across such inequality, near the end  of the proof ;

$$n>\frac{\varepsilon(-9\varepsilon + 31)}{27 + 6 \varepsilon}$$

Can we discard some of those epsilon terms or something else?

The problem (former inequality was a result of algebra mistake)is $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{2n-3}{3n+1}\right)^2$$
Proof:

$$\left|\left(\frac{2n-3}{3n+1}\right)^2 - \frac{4}{9}\right| < \varepsilon$$

$$\left|\frac{4n^2 - 12n +9}{9n^2 + 6n + 1} - \frac{4}{9}\right|<\varepsilon$$
$$\left|\frac{4n^2 - 12n + 9 - 36n^2 -24n-4}{81n^2+54n+9}\right|<\varepsilon$$
$$\left|\frac{-32n^2 - 36n + 5}{81n^2 + 54n +9}\right|<\varepsilon$$
Since this expression is always negative, because of absolute value I can multiply it times $(-1)$ and leave absolute value
$$\frac{32n^2 + 36n - 5}{81n^2 + 54n + 9}<\varepsilon$$
Here I'm estimating inequality by taking $-5$ from the top of the fraction and $+9$ from denominator
That leaves us with
$$\frac{32n^2 + 36n}{81n^2 + 54n}<\varepsilon$$
$$\frac{32n + 36}{81n + 54}<\varepsilon$$
$$\frac{32 + \frac{36}{n}}{81 + \frac{54}{n}} < \frac{32 + \frac{36}{n}}{81 } => n > \frac{1}{\varepsilon - \frac{8}{9}}$$
We can go further and discard $\frac{32}{81}$ in the last inequality? Can someone verify the proof?

Comment: i doubt you came across that. usually n is a pos integer and epsilon is very small. your thing is around epsilon^2

Comment: It'd be nice if you could tell us *how* this expression came up.

Comment: I chose to prove this with method specified in the topic , and limit to be $\frac{4}{9}$ First I squared the terms ,substracted $\frac{4}{9}$ algebraically, and there we have expression to rearrange to get n on one of the sides of inequality

Comment: aah I found the mistake, I didn't square the expression in the beginning of the proof

Comment: $27 + 6\epsilon > 27$ so $\frac{\epsilon(-9\epsilon+31)}{27+6\epsilon} < \frac {\epsilon(31 - 9\epsilon)}{27} < \frac {31\epsilon}{27} -\frac {9\epsilon^2}{27} < \frac {31\epsilon}{27}$ and... Mathworkers comment is valid.  This  is a small number made arbitririlay small by choosing small $\epsilon$. The means $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ for all epsilon and all $n$ which can only occur if this is a constant sequence, which it isn't.

Comment: Still not sure how you got the epsilons *in*.

Comment: It would be best if you can show the details of your calculation. In general when dealing such problems one does not solve inequalities via algebraic manipulation. Rather one tries to find suitable values of the variables so that the inequality can be guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Your epsilon term on the bottom only makes the bound smaller, so you can get rid of it at the cost of having a slightly larger value of $n$. Then one has $$n> \frac{-9\epsilon^2 +31\epsilon}{27} $$ which isn't so bad. That said, I'm curious what the original problem in question is, because this seems like an unlikely answer for this sort of thing, because as $\epsilon$ gets really small, this quantity goes to 0, where one should expect as $\epsilon$ gets small that the minimum required $n$ should be large. I suspect an algebra mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the purpose of the proof is to show that for any $\epsilon$ you can find an $N$ (such that…).

So if you obtain an expression of the form $N=f(\epsilon)$ where $f$ is defined on $(0,\infty)$, you are done.

What I mean is that simplifying the expression is of no use.

Comment: I am not commenting on the likeliness of the expression...